# Set up crontab every 4 hours 15 minutes

Tags: php, cron, sh

Below, I have this cron expression that runs every 4 hours:

```
* */4 * * *
```

However, I need it to run every 4 hours 15 minutes.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure it's impossible to do with a single cron expression. Create few rules like `15 4 * * *` + `30 8 * * *` etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems with this cron, I do not know if the expression will be incorrect, it will run every 4 hours but it does not stop, it runs every minute of the time it starts running

```
* */4 * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's impossible to implement it with just a single rule.

But you still can achieve the same using multiple rules:

```
0  0  * * * ...
15 4  * * * ...
30 8  * * * ...
45 12 * * * ...
0  17 * * * ...
15 21 * * * ...
```

**WARNING**: It would run with larger/shorter intervals on DST change though.